# How can I make my UIView visible in Xcode's Storyboard editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Please have a look at the screenshot that shows a part of a storyboard in Xcode. It is one controller. On the same level as the controller there are two `UIViews` "Date Picker View" and "Input Accessory View".
In the controller itself, they are shown in the bottom toolbar (see 2nd screenshot - the two icons to the right are tiny previews of the the views).
But how can I edit them? I cannot get them on the screen! I know they are there but I'd like to edit them (used to work before I made them parallel elements of the controller)! I tried right clicking, long clicking, zooming, panning, double clicking - nothing. If I drag one of the views into the controller's view, I can see them.
There are also outlets in the controller, referencing the views and the view can be used from code just fine. But editing them seems to have become impossible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you mean by editing? You can click on view and open right bar - inspector. There are all properties.

Comment: I mean, I cannot visually inspect the view. All I see is this tiny little preview in form of the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select them and edit their properties in the inspector, but there is no way to visually edit them short of physically moving them into one the scenes, editing them, and moving them back.

Comment: What's the point? Is that a bug of Xcode? Sounds like. I noticed that if I expand one of the views all the way down to a UIBarButtonItem that is in there, the view suddenly appears floating on top of everything - and then I cannot get rid of it anymore.