# Can't see UIView after added to UIViewController in storyboard separately in latest xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have drag & drop UIView to UIViewController in storyboard in xcode 5, it's added but i can't see that UIView in storyboard. Any one have solution?

In previous version of xcode, i did get it worked with the process described from following link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14515818/952440

But now it did not work in latest xcode 5.

For your information i have added screenshot from storyboard below:-

[image: Screenshot of document outline]

[image: Screenshot of bottom part of view controller]

Comment: Did either of the answers below help resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? This is not working for me either.

Comment: @Siriss No still did not find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, we can see view outside of UIViewController in storyboard in Xcode 7.

For your information i have added screenshot from Xcode 7.1 storyboard below:-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these views as subviews of the main view. Just drag them into the top `View`.

If you don't want to show them by default, set them as hidden and show them dynamically.

To edit them, you could create them in a separate xib and then copy-paste. That being said, I do not recommend to put views into storyboard that are not part of the application flow (the "story"). That is what xibs are for. If, however, the views really *belong* to this controller, then add them as subviews as suggested above.

Comment: You can still drag them outside of your main view as in Sunil's image, but I haven't found a way to modify them without dragging them into the main view (a huge oversight IMO).

Comment: I do not want to add UIView as subview to the main view, I want to add & modify it separately. It was worked in earlier version of xcode, but now in xcode 5, it is not working.

Comment: I don't get it. Then what is wrong with the screenshot above? The views are on the same level as the main `view`. This works exactly the same in Xcode 4 and 5.

Comment: @Mundi I mean to say that if i add another UIView as a subview of main  view it works fine, But I want to drag & drop another UIView outside the main ViewController's View.

Comment: In understand that - but that is what you are doing. So what is not working?

Comment: @Mundi ya, I added it outside but when I double click it in left pane it's not showing in right pane (i.e centre editor part where we can update views).

Comment: Here is a workaround: create a xib to edit the views, then copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your custom views "forgotPasswordView" and "SignUpView" must be subviews of your viewcontroller's view (LoginSignUp View Controller). From the screenshot it appears to lie outside and that is why they are not appearing up. You can simply drag and drop them at right place.

Additionally, make sure in your custom view classes you are implementing "initWithCode" initialization method for any initialization code.

Also see for reference:

[How can I make my UIView visible in Xcode's Storyboard editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840793/how-can-i-make-my-uiview-visible-in-xcodes-storyboard-editor)

Comment: In previous version of xcode, I did get worked as the process from link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard

Comment: But now i am not able to get worked it in xcode5 using process from above given link.